# Looping in VBA to pick up next cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops

i was wondering if you can help, i have 2 sheets a 'Masterfile' and 'Accounts' the aim is to copy each cell account number in Accounts worksheet starting from A2 to finish and copy this into B6 of the Masterfile worksheet. i need to save the file down on my desktop which i have written some code for but i cant seem to get my head around how to select the cell from accounts - copy into B6 - save and then move onto the next cell. can someone help?

```
Private Sub LOOPCELL()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Accounts")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Masterfile")

Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B6")

Dim filepath1 As String
Dim Filename1 As String
Dim Filename2 As String
Dim Filename3 As String
Path = "C:\Users\mukhan\Desktop"
Filename1 = Range("B6")
Filename2 = Range("D6")
Filename3 = Range("C8")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename1 & "-" & Filename2 & "-" & 
Filename3 & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Mujahid, 2 files? Accounts and Master?  You want to copy the entire data column from accounts (A) and paste it into Master (B) with an offset of about 4 rows (2 vs 6) all at once?  You don't have to do it cell by cell unless you have some operations you want to perform on the data before it is written into Master (arguably you could copy and then do the operations).  It is a worksheet range copy into another worksheet range paste (single cell as starting point).

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a few assumptions because you were not very specific in your question. The main thing is that my code assumes that both files are in the same workbook.

It selects the range `A2:A__` in "Accounts" (down to the last filled value in column A) and copies all of that data at once over to "Masterfile" starting at `B6`.

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Accounts")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Masterfile")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        ws1.Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B6")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mukhan\Desktop\Account " & ws1.Range("A" & i).Value2 & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanksi need to copy each cell from A2 to the last cell in 'Accounts' worksheet. then save onto my desktop. then copy A3,A4, and do the same until you get to the bottom of the list. the code is below but comes up with an Error. Compile error: Invalid or Unqualified Reference Private i have edited the code above to compile with your code. the file when saved needs to be in a particular format. which is picked up from the masterfile

Comment: @MujahidKhan when you say to the bottom of the list do you mean from A2 all the way to (for example) H2? If we're talking about left to right that's a simple change. Do you want each row to be saved as a separate document?

Comment: yes. so from A2 all the way to the bottom. A2,A3,A4 etc. then save as separate documents. so copy, a2 paste in b6 of masterfile, save file. copy a3, paste in B6 in masterfile save file. do this until we get to the bottom of the list

Comment: @MujahidKhan wait so it is only copying one single cell into the masterfile and it starts over? also this sounds like it might really fill up your desktop with files...

Comment: yes it may, but i will place these in folders. currently the code isn't working, and comes up with an error. Unqualified Reference Private Format. do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: i believe its this line: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @MujahidKhan yes i see the problem for that. However, i need you to answer these questions: 
1.) are 'accounts' and 'masterfile' inside of two different workbooks currently? 
2.) is it only supposed to copy one single cell (A2) over to the master?

Comment: 2 different worksheets on 1 workbook. only copy 1 cell over to the masterfile A2 yes which is then saved, the copy a3 save etc

Comment: @MujahidKhan okay then i think the updated code above should work

Comment: it states that the subscript out of range on line Set ws2 = Sheets("Masterfile")

Comment: @MujahidKhan you only get that error when the sheet "Masterfile" is not open, doest not exist, or is spelled wrong.